# How to run migrations again in rails when downgraded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I recently upgraded a rails application with a fairly large codebase from 6.0.1 to 7.0.5 with ruby 2.7.4 to 3.1.4. While the upgrade was successful upto staging env. We found a critical breaking change after deploying rails 7 due to which we had to revert it upto the lowest environment. Now in the lower environment, some migrations were generated in rails 7.0. Since now we had reverted changes to previous rails 6 version. Some migrations were generated while they were in rails 7. Now we want these migrations ( total 4) to run them again with rails 6 application. What is best way to do it safely and efficiently.

1. Delete the current rails 7 migrations and regenerate them in rails 6.
2. Manually change the ActiveRecord::Migrations version from 7.0 to 6.0 in these migrations and run them again on database.
   I don't want to lose old data
   Please suggest a way. Thanks in advance for answering.

Regards a small developer out there. :)

Planning to go for second approach.

Comment: Unless you're using some Rails 7 specific features in your migration you should be able to twiddle that version value.

Comment: Can you show us more information about the migrations? Are they simple, or complex, or...?